# Microservice Architecture with UI and Auth Server

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-security

I am thinking in moving our monolithic company portal into micro services . To do so i need create a portal HTML UI that has some kind of redundancy so we don't go down during updates and also full spring security including roles and permissions.

Currently i am stuck about deciding what is the best practice and where to PUT the UI .

[image: Sample of different micro services needed]

My Options:

1. Merge API Gateway and EDGE to have the UI same as any other micro service and forward /ui/** to it . (Back draw with this was the resources path as Zuul did not update them by adding the /ui prefix, so i thought in putting it as default forward)
2. Create two separate gateways as in the above diagram.
3. If 2 is the optimal solution , should the Rest Calls from HTML be sent directly to the API Gateway , or go to edge and from it to API Gateway ?

Comment: Are you using ZUUL as 'API Gateway' ?

Comment: yes , i did pass this and combined both api gateway and edge all together , full solution sample at [https://github.com/shahbour/microservices-security](https://github.com/shahbour/microservices-security)

Answer (score -1):

You may end up having different level of security for the two... so separate gateways might be better
I would send the requests directly to ali gateway and get rid of the extra hop.